# how can i reverse a list as well as its string elements using python using nested for loops?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, reverse

I have tried as below , it can be done using list comprehension [also without using in-build functions and techniques like [::-1] ], but want to do it using nested for loops as below ?

```
l=['temp','test']
l1=[]
for t in l:
  for i in t:
      l1.append(str(i[::-1]))
print(l1)

input: ['test','temp']
required output : ['pmet','tset']
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to reverse the order of the elements in the list, you can use reverse:

```
for i in reversed(array):
     print(i)
```

Or, you can use `array.reverse()`.

in order to reverse each string, you can use `[::-1]`, for example:

```
txt = "Hello World"[::-1]
print(txt)
```

output:

```
dlroW olleH
```

Looking at the code you added, you can do something like this:

```
l=['temp','test']
reverse_l=[]
reverse_l = [item[::-1] for item in l] # This is list comprehensions, you can read about it in the link at the end of the answer
reverse_l.reverse()
print(l)
print(reverse_l)
```

output:

```
['temp', 'test']
['tset', 'pmet']
```

A solution without list comprehension:

```
l=['temp','test']
reverse_l=[]
for item in l:
    item = item[::-1]
    reverse_l.append(item)
reverse_l.reverse()
print(l)
print(reverse_l)
```

You can find information about list Comprehensions in python [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Comment: thanks Eyal , actually i was looking for  an answer without using list comprehension . what will be the approach ? i understand outer for loop is for each element in the list and the inner for loop will be for traversing the each list element .

Comment: @SameerKumar I added a solution without using list comprehension. In the future, please don't change the question's requirements after people answered.

Answer (score 1):

Using nested loops:

```py
l=['temp','test']
print([''.join([w[i] for i in range(len(w)-1, -1, -1)]) for w in reversed(l)])
```

Output:

```py
['pmet', 'tset']
```

Comment: Your input is not the same as the OP.

Comment: Thanks Joan , can help me by simplifying the list comprehensions "[''.join([w[i] for i in range(len(w)-1, -1, -1)]"  , i mean can you please simplify it without using list comprehension .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
l=['temp','test']
l1=[]
for t in l:
  l1.append(t[::-1])
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop:

```py
l = ['temp', 'test']
l1 = [
    word[::-1]
    for word in l
]
print(l1)
```

output:

```
['pmet', 'tset']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
input_list = ['test', 'temp']
input_list.reverse()
print(list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], input_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i][::-1]
l = l[::-1]
```

you don't need nested loops for desired output you have given.